# Calling an image from CSS

Tags: image, html, css

- My .html files are all in `Assignment1/*.html` files
- My CSS file is in `Assignment1/style/cssfile.css`
- My images are in `Assignment1/images/images.png`

How do i call an image from `Assignment1/style/cssfile.css` to `Assignment1/images/images.png` file?

I can`t do it like the html files as i could just forward the folders to go through. I am trying to do:

`.top {background-image: url("Assignment1/images/deco1400.png");}`

from the css file to no avail.

How can I reference my image files from my CSS that are in different directories.

Comment: use `../` to go back up the folder where the css is then back into images for exam `../images/file.png`

Answer (score 5):

try

```
background-image: url("../images/deco1400.png");
```

Your tree structure is like

```
Assignment1
  style
    style.css <- you are here
  images
    img1.png
```

so either you need to go 1 level up (`..`) and then enter images OR you need to give absolute path /images/img1.png (note `/` at the beginning). Both should work, assuming Assignment is your root directory

UPDATE: you might be interested in reading about relative and absolute paths.

Comment: great response time and it worked! thanks alot. could you explain what the .. does?

Comment: you can treat `..` as alias to parent directory. Lets assume you have file in `C:/folder/another_folder/file.txt`, then `..` in `folder` points to `C:` and `..` in `another_folder` points to `folder`. In your example you are located `style` folder, so if you have written just `images/img.png` then it would look it in this `style` directory. By adding `../` at the beginning you are telling it to search for `images` in the parent of `style`. Hope that helps